# Toggling marginTop without making an element disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've thrown together a cool little script that will make my search box appear using jQuery UI. However, there are links above the search box that must move up at the same speed as well. For this, the margin-top must be adjusted, but by toggling the margin-top, it seems it is disappearing.

Does anyone know how I can toggle the margin-top without making the links disappear AND keep the speed as close as possible to the other one?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pwcustomsearch').hide();
    $("#pwcustomsearchlink").click(function () {
        var effect = 'slide';
        var options = { direction: 'down' };
        var duration = 400;
        $('.pwcustomsearch').toggle(effect, options, duration);
        $('.social-media').toggle({"marginTop": "15px"});
    })
});
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/1030/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toggle()` is adding `display:none` as an inline style to your element, therefore it disappears.

Use `.animate()` instead to change the top margin.

See my updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/1032/

EDIT: Updated the fiddle again to make the toggling work properly.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I was using toggle() was so the top links could be toggled back into position after it was clicked again. Any idea how that can work?